# How to insert data into two tables with t-sql

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

This question is very similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225965/how-do-insert-data-into-two-different-tables) so I hope this isn't too redundant.

I am new to T-SQL and I am trying to understand if there is a different/better approach to inserting records into two tables.

For example I have a form with name and address, in my DB this is represented with two tables ( client and address) on the most basic level if I wanted to insert the following:

Name fields (first, middle last age) to name table and address (street number, street name, city, state, zip) to address table  with name being the primary table could someone point me in the right direction as to the best way to do this in SQL Server / T-sql? Or would it be the same as within MySQL syntax by inserting the person first and then selecting the last inserted user getting the id and then adding the address and id (as the fk) to the address table?

I'd also appreciate any links or additional reading on the best approach.

Cheers (and thanks in advance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two inserts.  After you do the first insert into the client table use @@identity to get the ID of the inserted record.

```
INSERT INTO client VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin')

SET @clientKey = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO address VALUES (@clientKey, '123 Elm')
```

Comment: In SQL Server `Scope_Identity()` is generally a much better choice than `@@Identity`.  The latter is subject to side effects from triggers and the like.  Unfortunately both of them may be wrong: [SCOPE_IDENTITY() sometimes returns incorrect value](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value).  A workaround is to use an `OUTPUT` clause to capture the new id(s).

Answer (score 1):

how about you create a `STORED PROCEDURE` for this?

example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Registration.IdentifyStudentsByState
    @Gdr nvarchar(20),
    @StateOrProvince char(2)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT FullName = LastName + ', N' + FirstName,
           DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) AS Age,Gender
    FROM Registration.Students
    WHERE (Gender = @Gdr) AND (State = @StateOrProvince);
END
```

so in your case you should write something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertData
    @iFirst varchar(50),
    @iMiddle varchar(50),
    @iLast varchar(50),
    @iAge varchar(50),
    @iStreetNo varchar(50),
    @iStreetName varchar(50),
    @iCity varchar(50),
    @iState varchar(50),
    @iZip varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT tableNameA(First, Middle, Last, Age) VALUES (@iFirst,@iMiddle,@iLast,@iAge);
    INSERT tableNameB(StreetNo,Streetname,City, State,Zip) VALUES (@iStreetNo,@iStreetName,@iCity,@iState,@iZip);
END
```

**USAGE**

```
EXEC InsertData 'john','mm','doe','45','asd','fg','fgh','fgh','fgh';
```

***NOTE: The above illustration is just an example how to create a `STORED PROCEDURE`, you can modify the `PARAMETERs`, the `DATA TYPEs` used and the queries. I Hope this helps you. Thanks!***

Comment: In your example how would the foreign key be set in the address table. I see how the insert works but how is the relationship set between the two tables?